# C - Floating Point Exception (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, pixel, cycle, floating-point-exceptions

This function is supposed to, pixel by pixel, blur the image by turning the color of each pixel on the mean of the colors around it in a 2n+1 "radius".

(The part where it skips to the next pixel is already implemented, don't worry).

I successfully compiled this code:

```
void
blur_pixels(image *img, pixel *p, size_t i, size_t j)
{
  //i = current height of pixel, j = current width of pixel
  int side = 2*blurRate+1;
  int total = 0;
  int leftRight = i-blurRate;
  int upDown = j-blurRate;
  int tmpHr = 0, tmpHg = 0, tmpHb = 0;

  for(; upDown < j+blurRate; upDown++) {
    if(upDown >= 0 && upDown < img->height) {
      for(; leftRight < i+blurRate; leftRight++) {
        if(leftRight >= 0 && leftRight < img->width) {
          tmpHr += (p+leftRight)->r;
          tmpHg += (p+leftRight)->g;
          tmpHb += (p+leftRight)->b;
          total++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p->r=tmpHr/total;
  p->g=tmpHg/total;
  p->b=tmpHb/total;
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following exception:

```
Floating point exception
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure `total` is >0 after the loop?

Comment: Probably division by zero. Use a debugger.

Comment: Probably total is 0.

Comment: OT: You don't use `upDown` to adjust the pixel pointer, so you will always be reading the same row (row 0) of the image. That's not relevant to your error, though. (Also, I don't understand the use of a global rather than passing `blurRate` as a parameter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is preforming division by 0 with `p->r=tmpHr/total;`

`total` is likely zero because compiler warnings are not turned on showing the mixed signed/unsigned math of the `for()` loop.   Turn on all compiler warnings.

The compare `upDown < j+blurRate` and other code is done using unsigned math, likely not as OP expects and the inner `total++;` never happens.  If `upDown < 0`, then `upDown` in `upDown < j+blurRate` becomes a large unsigned value.  Then compare is false.

```
size_t j  // an unsigned type
...
int upDown = j-blurRate;
...
for(; upDown < j+blurRate; upDown++) {  // not firing
```

One solution would be to use only `int` variables. A more robust solution  would use unsigned math, yet more of the higher level code would be needed for a good answer.

Something like:

```
blur_pixels(image *img, pixel *p, size_t i, size_t j) {
  //i = current height of pixel, j = current width of pixel
  size_t side = 2u*blurRate+1;
  size_t total = 0;
  size_t leftRight = (i > blurRate) ? i-blurRate : 0;
  size_t upDown = (j > blurRate) ? j-blurRate : 0;
  int tmpHr = 0, tmpHg = 0, tmpHb = 0;

  for(; upDown < j+blurRate; upDown++) {
    if (upDown < img->height) {
      // I suspect leftRight needs to be set here each iteration
      size_t leftRight = (i > blurRate) ? i-blurRate : 0;
      for(; leftRight < i+blurRate; leftRight++) {
        if (leftRight < img->width) {
          tmpHr += (p+leftRight)->r;
          tmpHg += (p+leftRight)->g;
          tmpHb += (p+leftRight)->b;
          total++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (total) {
    p->r = tmpHr/total;
    p->g = tmpHg/total;
    p->b = tmpHb/total;
  } else {
    p->r = p->g = p->b = 0;
  }
}
```